# Axiomatic proof that all points of an open set are interior points

Tags: general-topology

In "Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Rudin the following definition (f) to open sets: a set is open if all of its points are interior points
[image]

Sidney Morris' Topology Without Tears, however, defines open sets as members of a topology, a set with the following axioms:
 Si. [image: enter i]

I would like to prove that botn definitions are equivalent.

Comment: It doesn't need to be countable.

Comment: You want a proof of a definition?

Comment: I've described two definitions of open sets: (1) open sets as sets of interior points and (2) open sets as members of a topology. I want to show that both are equivalent.

Comment: That is not what you have written in the question. You are being downvoted because it's unclear what you are asking, maybe you want to edit.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I've just edited it to make it more precise.

Answer (score 4):

Let $E$ a set such that every point of $E$ is an interior point of $E$.

By definition of an interior point
$\forall x\in E$, there exists an open set $O_x$ such that $x\in O_x$ and $O_x\subset E$.

Then:
$$E=\bigcup_{x\in E}O_x$$

$E$ is open as an union of open sets.

Comment: Why can this Union be infinite, and why must the Intersection of sets of interior points be finite?